# Bounds on the spectral radius and vertices degree

Tags: graph-theory

Please, i need help with proof of this theorem.

Let G be a connected graph with m edges and degree sequence $d_1,d_2,\dots ,d_n$, then

$λ_1≥\frac{m}{R(G)}$.

where $R(G) = \sum_{uv\in E} \frac{1}{\sqrt{d(u)d(v)}}$ is Randić index and $λ_1$ is the largest eigenvalue (spectral radius).

Please help, i have tried to use fact, that $λ_1 \le max_{v_iv_j \in E(G)}\{\sqrt{d(i)d(j)}\}$, but it's not right, it finally shows that
$R(G) \ge \frac{m}{max_{v_iv_j \in E(G)}\{\sqrt{d(i)d(j)}\}}$
but it is not greater than or equal to $\frac{m}{\lambda_1}$.

EDIT

I also tried that $\lambda_1 \ge \frac{1}{m}\sum_{v_iv_j \in E(G)} \sqrt{d(i)d(j)}  $ but it finally goes to $\lambda_1 \ge \frac{R(G)}{m}$. . .

Answer (score 1):

This is Corollary 2.11 in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390156N).

If you assume the inequality you made in the edit (the second inequality in Proposition 2.8), you can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(\sum_{ij\in E(G)} \sqrt{d_id_j})(\sum_{ij\in E(G)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{d_id_j}})\geq m^2$ to get $\lambda_1\geq\frac{\sum_{ij\in E(G)} \sqrt{d_id_j}}{m}\geq\frac{m^2}{m\sum_{ij\in E(G)} \sqrt{d_id_j}}=\frac{m}{R(G)}$.